# How to provide easy multilanguage text in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have some short text that I want to ship in the currently active language. What's the most easy way to do it? Example: I have the text "the cat", but when someone from spain uses the app, he/she wants to read "el gato". Is there a standard way to do it easily with UIKit? They're pretty simple texts only. I can imagine some kind of property list and feeding it with a key and locale, and getting the appropriate text snippet out of there.

Answer (score -1):

Check out NSLocalizedString.